# jquery Filter dropdown and set selected not working

Tags: jquery, filter, html-select

I'm still new to JQuery, Javascript but this is what I have:

Here is my script:

```
/* Check for zip code input */
$('#editZipCode').keyup(function() {

    var inputString = $('#editZipCode').val();

    if(inputString.length == 5) {   

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"/zip_code_search/"+inputString,

        success: function(data) {

            if(data.length > 0) {

                var parts = data.split(':');

                $('select[name="city"] option').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == parts[0]; }).prop('selected', true);
                $('select[name="state"] option').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == parts[1]; }).prop('selected', true);

            }else{

                $('select[name="city"] option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true);
                $('select[name="state"] option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true);

            }
        }

    });


    }else{
                $('select[name="city"] option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true);
                $('select[name="state"] option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true);
    }

});
```

Here is my html:

```
<form action="" method="">

 <input type="text" id="editZipCode" name="zip_code">

 <select id="StateOption" name="state">
   <option value="0">-Select-</option>
   <option value="AK">AK</option>
   <option value="AL">AL</option>
   <option value="AR">AR</option>
   <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
 </select>

 <select id="CityOption" name="city">
   <option value="0">-Select-</option>
   <option value="ADAK">ADAK</option>
   <option value="AKIACHAK">AKIACHAK</option>
   <option value="AKIAK">AKIAK</option>
 </select>

</form>
```

The problem im facing is that it will not set the selected option of the CityOptions dropdown, the StateOptions dropdown works fine.

When I enter the zip code it sets the StateOption dropdown box to the one that matches the one returned from the ajax call but not the CityOption.

If I log parts[0] or parts[1] to the console they both print out the city/state that matches the zip code entered in the input field but again it will only set the state option to the matched value not the city option.

Am I just missing something obvious here?

Thanks in advance!

p.s. I'm using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js if thats important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm slightly confused by this line:

`.filter(function() { return $(this).text() == parts[0]; })`  As I don't fully understand your intent with it.  But I shall carry on anyway.

Now it's kind of hard to fully debug your code without a working example, but I will provide a possible solution but mainly a way to debug/test what you want to happen.

First off, I would possibly change the line above to something like this:

`$('select[name="city"] option[value="'+ parts[0] +'"]').prop('selected', true);`

But that might not be critical.

To test what's going on you are on the right path with console.log.  If you are using chrome I would add a `debugger;` right after `var parts = data.split(':');`   This will cause your code to pause here so that you can do some testing (you'll need to have the developer tools open).   In the console tab you can now test at that point in your code.  So you could type `parts` and it should print out your array of two items.  This power comes from being able to test in the console something like this:

`$('select[name="city"] option[value="'+ parts[0] +'"]')`

This should return the option object if there is a match, if not you'll get a `[]` meaning that jQuery queried the page and couldn't find a match.  If it does have a match then you can try that code again except with the `prop('selected',true);` at the end to see if it's working.

This should hopefully help you in being able to debug at the critical point and to understand a little more about what jQuery is doing.  You are on your way to becoming a jQuery master!

Comment: I have done like you said and your right it printed out [] if I try $('select[name="state"] option[value="'+ parts[1] +'"]'); it prints [<option value=​"IA">​IA​</option>​] Kinda of strange it's not finding a match when I know that it does exist or at least that the city is listed in the dropdown and that parts[0] contains the name of the city. Very Strange! lol but this is helpfull.

Comment: Well then you need to keep using jQuery to find why it's not matching.  So at your breakpoint do something like `$('select[name="city"] option');` to see if it can even find the city options.  If it can, then compare your parts[0] to the value on the option to make sure they match perfectly (including capitalization).  Take small steps to check your sanity and see where jQuery is failing to get what you expect it to.